# preventing an input from being certain characters

Tags: c, logic

The logic in my code is not working right. I dont want the user input to be anything but A-Z, a-z, 1-9 and _. I don't know what I am doing wrong! Basically, if the user enters something that isnt those characters it will print an error.
Here is part of my code:

```
            if(((outname[i]<'a'||outname[i]>'z')&&(outname[i]<'A'||outname[i]>'Z')&&(outname[i]<'0'||outname[i]>'9'))&&(outname[i]!='_')){
                    if (count_attempts>1){
```

Comment: Try [isalpha](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cctype/isalpha/) and [isdigit](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cctype/isdigit/).

Comment: What you have looks OK.  Please provide a [minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of the issue.

Comment: I have added more of my code

Comment: You need to reset `i` to 0 after the `scanf`. So that the loop starts checking the new input from the beginning of the string. If that is not the problem then please describe what the currently observed behaviour of your program is.

Comment: Added output to description

Comment: Ok, I think it is time you posted a [Minimal Complete and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). You need to show how that block of code is called in context. Clearly there are other `scanf` and `printf` calls you are not showing. We can't debug the code if you leave out parts which may be crucial to the problem.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

May be you want to do something like this:

```
    if( (str[i]>='a') && (str[i] <= 'z') ||
        (str[i]>='A') && (str[i] <= 'Z') ||
        (str[i]>='0') && (str[i] <= '9') ||
        (str[i] =='_') )
        printf("TRUE\n");
    else
        printf("FALSE\n");
```

Comment: The logic as posted is sound.  It says "IF character is not lower case AND not upper case AND not a digit AND not _ THEN the character is invalid".